# how to let the user change the password for a python program that saves each password and username in a different file when you create the account?

Tags: python

```
import json

def login(usr):
    uN = input("enter your username , if new user enter new username: ")
    pW = input("enter your password , if new user enter new password: ")
    if uN or pW is not "":
        pass
    else:
        print("Invalid username or password")
        return
```

> checking for username in the file

```
    if uN in usr.keys():
```

> checking for the password in the file

```
        if pW == usr[uN]: 
            print("Welcome back " + uN) 




       else:
```

> if the password doesn't match it throws an error

```
            print("Incorrect password.")
            return False
    else:
        print("Hello, new person.")   
        usr[uN] = pW
```

> here it is writing to the file

```
    writeUsers(usr)
    return True

def readUsers():
    try:
        with open("users.json", "r") as f:
            return json.load(f)
 except FileNotFoundError:
        return {}
```

> so if the user wants to change his or her password what is the code to make it happend

Comment: It sounds like you just need to update a json object then resave it. Check this page: https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-update-a-json-file-in-python

Comment: ok thank you for the info I checked the page and it helped a lot